# How can I loop over pages and get data from every page with selenium?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, web-scraping

I want to do a google search and collect the links to all hits so that I can click those links and extract data from them after collecting all links. How can I get the link from every hit?

I've tried several solutions like using a for loop and a while True statement. I'll show some examples of the code below. I either get no data at all or I get only data (links) from 1 webpage. Can someone please help me figure out how to iterate over every page of the google search and get all the links so I can continue scraping those pages? I'm new to using Selenium so I'm sorry if the code doesn't make much sense, I've really confused myself with this one.

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('condition')
sleep(0.5)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(0.5)

while True:
    try:
        urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
        for url in urls
        urls = [url.text for url in urls]

    sleep(0.5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_id('pnnext')
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    sleep(0.5)
    element.click()
```

```
urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
urls = [url.text for url in urls]
sleep(0.5)

element = driver.find_element_by_id('pnnext')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
sleep(0.5)
element.click()
```

```
while True:
    next_page_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('pnnext')
    if len(next_page_btn) <1:
        print("no more pages left")
        break
    else: 
        urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')
        urls = [url.text for url in urls]
    sleep(0.5)

    element = driver.find_element_by_id('pnnext')
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    sleep(0.5)
    element.click()
```

I expect a list of all urls from the google search that can be opened by Selenium so Selenium can get data from those pages.

I only get a list of urls from one page. The next step (scraping those pages) is working fine. But due to this restriction I only get 10 results while I'd like to see all results.

Comment: some weirdness in how your code is formatted in the question, so i am not sure this is actually the issue but it looks like you are redefining your `urls` each time you go to a next page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code. I have changed a bit.Hope this help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys('condition')
search.submit()

while True:
    next_page_btn =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='pnnext']")
    if len(next_page_btn) <1:
        print("no more pages left")
        break
    else:
        urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='iUh30']")
        urls = [url.text for url in urls]
        print(urls)

    element =WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'pnnext')))
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.click()
```

OutPut :

```
['https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condition', 'https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/condition', 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/condition', 'https://www.dictionary.com/browse/condition', 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condition', 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/condition', 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/condition', 'www.businessdictionary.com/definition/condition.html', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition', 'https://www.definitions.net/definition/condition', '', '', '', '']
['https://www.thefreedictionary.com/condition', 'https://www.thefreedictionary.com/conditions', 'https://www.yourdictionary.com/condition', 'https://www.foxnews.com/.../woman-battling-rare-suicide-disease-says-chronic-pain-con...', 'https://youngminds.org.uk/find-help/conditions/', 'www.road.is/travel-info/road-conditions-and-weather/', 'https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions', 'https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/scripts/conditions/', 'https://www.bhf.org.uk/informationsupport/conditions', 'https://www.gov.uk/driving-medical-conditions']
['https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have.../check-visa-details-and-condition...', 'https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions/', 'https://www.ofgem.gov.uk/licences-industry-codes-and.../licence-conditions', 'https://www.healthychildren.org/English/health-issues/conditions/Pages/default.aspx', 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html', 'https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms.../general-conditions-of-entitlement', 'https://www.rnib.org.uk/eye-health/eye-conditions', 'https://www.mdt.mt.gov/travinfo/map/mtmap_frame.html', 'https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions', 'https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp']
['https://www.tremblant.ca/mountain-village/mountain-report', 'https://www.equibase.com/static/horsemen/horsemenareaCB.html', 'https://www.abebooks.com/books/rarebooks/...guide/.../guide-book-conditions.shtml', 'https://nces.ed.gov/programs/coe/', 'https://www.cdc.gov/wtc/conditions.html', 'https://snowcrows.com/raids/builds/engineer/engineer/condition/']
['https://www.millenniumassessment.org/en/Condition.html', 'https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition', 'horsemen.ustrotting.com/conditions.cfm', 'https://lb.511ia.org/ialb/', 'https://www.nps.gov/deva/planyourvisit/conditions.htm', 'https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/', 'https://www.spine-health.com/conditions', 'https://www.tripcheck.com/', 'https://hb.511.nebraska.gov/', 'https://www.gamblingcommission.gov.uk/.../licence-conditions-and-codes-of-practice....']
['https://sports.yahoo.com/andrew-bogut-credits-beer-improved-022043569.html', 'https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html', 'https://www.disability-benefits-help.org/disabling-conditions', 'https://www.planningportal.co.uk/info/200126/applications/60/consent_types/12', 'https://www.leafly.com/news/.../qualifying-conditions-for-medical-marijuana-by-state', 'https://www.hhs.gov/healthcare/about-the-aca/pre-existing-conditions/index.html', 'https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tRcHAAAAQAAJ', 'www.onr.org.uk/documents/licence-condition-handbook.pdf', 'https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S0sGAAAAQAAJ']
['https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KSjLDvXH6iUC', 'https://www.arcgis.com/apps/Viewer/index.html?appid...', 'https://www.trappfamily.com/trail-conditions.htm', 'https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=n_g0AQAAMAAJ', 'https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=1492586277', 'https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JDjQ2-HV3l8C', 'https://www.newsshopper.co.uk/.../17529825.teenager-no-longer-in-critical-condition...', 'https://nbcpalmsprings.com/.../bicyclist-who-collided-with-minivan-hospitalized-in-cri...']
['https://www.stuff.co.nz/.../4yearold-christchurch-terrorist-attack-victim-in-serious-but-...', 'https://www.shropshirestar.com/.../woman-in-serious-condition-after-fall-from-motor...', 'https://www.expressandstar.com/.../woman-in-serious-condition-after-fall-from-motor...', 'https://www.independent.ie/.../toddler-rushed-to-hospital-in-serious-condition-after-hit...', 'https://www.nhsinform.scot/illnesses-and-conditions/ears-nose-and-throat/vertigo', 'https://www.rochdaleonline.co.uk/.../teenage-cyclist-in-serious-condition-after-collisio...', 'https://www.irishexaminer.com/.../baby-of-woman-found-dead-in-cumh-in-critical-cond...', 'https://touch.nihe.gov.uk/index/corporate/housing.../house_condition_survey.htm', 'https://www.nami.org/Learn-More/Mental-Health-Conditions', 'https://www.weny.com/.../update-woman-in-critical-but-stable-condition-after-being-s...']
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for getting all the urls so that's step 1. Now I'll have to figure out how to get data from all the urls (currently still getting data from only 10 urls). But I'll see if I can fix that myself first. Thanks so much!