# How to retrieve information from a website using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have come across a task where I have to retrieve information from a website using a crawler. (url: https://www.onepa.gov.sg/cat/adventure)

The website has multiple products. For each product, it contains link that directs us to a webpage of that individual product, and I want to collect all of the links.

[screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXp7L.png)

[screenshot of the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj4CR.png)

For example, one of the product has name: KNOTTY STUFF, and I expect to get the href of /class/details/c026829364

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_soup(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html.parser")
    return soup

url = "https://www.onepa.gov.sg/cat/adventure"
soup = get_soup(url)
for i in soup.findAll("a", {"target": "_blank"}):
    print(i.get("href"))
```

The output is `https://tech.gov.sg/report_vulnerability https://www.pa.gov.sg/feedback` 
Which does not include what I was looking for: /class/details/c026829364

I appreciate any helps or assistance, thank you!

Comment: Try searching for `/class/details/c026829364` in `plain_text`.

Comment: I would use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the page uses [dynamic javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A368P.png) to prepare the spans links. So you won't be able to accomplish it using normal `requests`.

Instead you should use selenium with a webdriver to load all the links before scraping.

You can try downloading ChromeDriver executable [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). And if you paste it in the same folder as your script you can run:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"  # CHANGE THIS PATH IF NOT SAME FOLDER
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)

url = "https://www.onepa.gov.sg/cat/adventure"
driver.get(url)

try:
    # Waint links to be ready
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gridTitle > span > a"))
    )
except WebDriverException:
    print("Page offline")  # Added this because page is really unstable :(

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".gridTitle > span > a")
links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elements]
print(links)
```

Comment: Hi, does this require me to install Chrome Driver? The error given to me was WebDriverException: Message: 'Desktop\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home.

Comment: Sorry, the link broke in the answer. You have just to [download ChromeDriver executable](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and place it in the same folder as your script.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I have downloaded and ran the program successfully but I have another question. For some categories, it has multiple pages but the url remained the same ie the martial arts category (https://www.onepa.gov.sg/cat/martial-arts). It means that I couldn't loop the pages in the url, is there anyway that I can just load all the elements in the url so I can collect all wanted information? Otherwise, the code will only collect information in the first page.

Comment: I don't think the site allows you to load all the 1k elements on one page. So I recommend you to take a look on [how to loop over multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381806/how-can-i-loop-over-pages-and-get-data-from-every-page-with-selenium) with selenium

Answer (score 0):

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. However, the links are available via sending a `POST` request to:

```
https://www.onepa.gov.sg/sitecore/shell/WebService/Card.asmx/GetCategoryCard
```

Try searching for the links using the built-in [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regex) module

```
import re
import requests


URL = "https://www.onepa.gov.sg/sitecore/shell/WebService/Card.asmx/GetCategoryCard"

headers = {
    "authority": "www.onepa.gov.sg",
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "origin": "https://www.onepa.gov.sg",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "referer": "https://www.onepa.gov.sg/cat/adventure",
    "cookie": "visid_incap_2318972=EttdbbMDQMeRolY+XzbkN8tR5l8AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAjkedvsgJ6Zxxk2+19JR8Z; SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=d6377e975a10472b868e47de9a8a0baf; _sp_ses.075f=*; ASP.NET_SessionId=vn435hvgty45y0fcfrold2hx; sc_pview_shuser=; __AntiXsrfToken=30b776672938487e90fc0d2600e3c6f8; BIGipServerpool_PAG21PAPRPX00_443=3138016266.47873.0000; incap_ses_7221_2318972=5BC1VKygmjGGtCXbUiU2ZNRS5l8AAAAARKX8luC4fGkLlxnme8Ydow==; font_multiplier=0; AMCVS_DF38E5285913269B0A495E5A%40AdobeOrg=1; _sp_ses.603a=*; SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE=A675B7DEE34A47F9803ED6D4EC4A8355|0|vn435hvgty45y0fcfrold2hx; _sp_id.603a=d539f6d1-732d-4fca-8568-e8494f8e584c.1608930022.1.1608930659.1608930022.bfeb4483-a418-42bb-ac29-42b6db232aec; _sp_id.075f=5e6c62fd-b91d-408e-a9e3-1ca31ee06501.1608929756.1.1608930947.1608929756.73caa28b-624c-4c21-9ad0-92fd2af81562; AMCV_DF38E5285913269B0A495E5A%40AdobeOrg=1075005958%7CMCIDTS%7C18622%7CMCMID%7C88630464609134511097093602739558212170%7CMCOPTOUT-1608938146s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.1",
}

data = '{"cat":"adventure", "subcat":"", "sort":"", "filter":"[filter]", "cp":"[cp]"}'

response = requests.post(URL, data=data,  headers=headers)
print(re.findall(r"<Link>(.*)<", response.content.decode("unicode_escape")))
```

Output:

```
['/class/details/c026829364', '/interest/details/i000027991', '/interest/details/i000009714']
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering why I got a different output when running the same code you provided.

Comment: The output was: ['/class/details/c026831851', '/class/details/c026831729', '/class/details/c026831723', '/class/details/c026831728', '/class/details/c026831722', '/class/details/c026831721', '/class/details/c026831720', '/class/details/c026831718', '/class/details/c026831719', '/class/details/c026831610', '/class/details/c026831600', '/class/details/c026832480', '/class/details/c026832459', '/class/details/c026831585', '/class/details/c026831572', '/class/details/c026832456', '/class/details/c026832479', '/class/details/c026832453', '/class/details/c026831154'...